# Umbraco Content Template Not Showing When Trying To Add New Page

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

In an instance of Umbraco 7 I have two main document types - a landing page and content page. Each of these has a corresponding template i.e. Landing Page has a default template called Landing Page.

In the production environment the editors have created Content Templates pages they have created in the content tree for both of these document types.

When trying to create a new Landing Page the content templates for this type are listed along with "Blank" but when trying to create a new Content Page the content templates for Content Page are not listed.

I have checked to see if these templates exist in the Settings area of Umbraco and can see them ok. They are also using the correct document type and template.

I have tried to replicate this in the test environment and locally but everything is working as expected so I'm a little confused as to why this wouldn't be working in production.

Version of Umbraco: 7.12.3.

Does anyone know of a reason why content templates wouldn't show for a specific type?

Comment: Do all of the expected templates exist in the "Allowed Templates" section of the doctype?

Comment: Yeah - the doc types only have one allowed template and they are as expected. Clicking on the template in the content template takes me to the same one as the doc type uses